# Accessing mongodb collection in Meteor without a template

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, meteor

I have a collection with some data I brought from JSON file: `Data.insert( JSON.parse(Assets.getText('data.json')) );`. I want to create a var with all the data in a JS file that is not part of a template.

Should I just do `var data = Data.find({}).fetch()[0]`?
Sometimes the fetch returns empty and I get `undefined` so I'm guessing this is not the best way. What would be the correct way?

Comment: The `fetch` is not needed if you only need the first element. There is `findOne` for that exact case. Your issue may come from two different sources: The data comes from the server and has not arrived yet when you try to access it on the client (pub/sub latency issue, already answered thoroughly on SO); or you insert this data on the same side you access it and thus it is a file load order issue (also answered on SO). We need more details, namely the context of the insertion and the read to know what matches this case.

Comment: @kyll I insert the data into the collection from a json file on server startup. I need to heavily manipulate the raw data on the client before using it inside a template (I need to create raw dom objects and once they are ready, insert them into the template). Does this answer your question?

Comment: It does. Then, how do you obtain this data on the client? Through a publication?

Comment: @Kyll I'm still with autopublish, so I just access the collection like I said in the question

Comment: The fact that sometimes it works and sometimes it returns `undefined` strongly seems like a publish issue... However I don't know how `autopublish` works exactly. If you try to access the data with a method instead, how does it work?

Comment: @Kyll what do you mean by "with a method"? The `undefined` problem stopped when I stopped rewriting the collection on startup. I tried using `upsert` because I thought it might be what I need (update the collection only if there are changes) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the data isn't always there at the time you  call `find` (aside, you can use `findOne`).

Based on your comments on the question sounds like maybe you want to put the function that calls `find` inside a `Tracker.autorun()` so that your variable updates as new data comes in. If that code is not in a template helper it won't get re run as the data comes in from the server. If something in your template depends on it then it may make sense to put it inside a helper in your template.

Alternately if the data won't change after server startup then you can use publish and subscribe mechanisms to declare your data `ready()` after it's loaded on the server, then do the client post processing in an `onReady()` callback in your `subscribe()` function, something like:

On the server:

```
Meteor.publish("startupData", function (){ 
    if (!this.userId) 
        return this.ready();
    else 
        return StartUpData.find({userId: this.userId});
}
```

On the client:

```
var startupData;
Meteor.subscribe("startupData", function(){
    var initStartupData = StartUpData.find({}) //will get all the published data for this user
    startupData = doPostProcessing(initStartupData)
}
```

Additionally, in the latter case (unchanging initial data), you'll want to make sure any template that depends on the data doesn't render until the data's arrived. I've handled this case in the past using IronRouter's `waiton` feature with something like this:

```
Router.route('/path', {
  name: "waiting_route_name",
  waitOn: function(){
    return Meteor.subscribe('yoursub', function post_process_onready(){
        //post processing here
    });
  },
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  action: function(){
    this.render("the_template_name")
  }
})
```

Having said that... If there's a template that depends on certain data, often that's a sign that the data should be either provided in a helper to that template or as the data context for the template. And Meteor will automatically handle re-rendering as that data arrives/changes.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to get the data on client startup? Or how to load the template only when this data is ready?